# How to solve Graph execution error during my model training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, image-classification

I build the inception v3 model from scratch. When I tried to train my model with a popular data set, dogs and cats from Kaggle, I faced **Graph execution error**. The reason might be my data set; I guess some data are not in the RGB scale, or it might be other causes.

[**Data Set**](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/shaunthesheep/microsoft-catsvsdogs-dataset)

> Model compile

```
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics= ['accuracy'])
```

> Data Preprocess

```
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.inception_v3.preprocess_input) \
    .flow_from_directory(directory=trin_path, target_size=(299,299), classes=['dogs', 'cats'], batch_size=10)
valid_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.inception_v3.preprocess_input) \
    .flow_from_directory(directory=valid_path, target_size=(299,299), classes=['dogs', 'cats'], batch_size=10)
test_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.inception_v3.preprocess_input) \
     .flow_from_directory(directory=test_path, target_size=(299,299), classes=['dogs', 'cats'], batch_size=10, shuffle=False)
```

> Model Fit

```
r = model.fit(x=train_batches, validation_data=valid_batches, epochs=5)
```

> The Error Occur

```
Epoch 1/5
 72/500 [===>..........................] - ETA: 1:14 - loss: 0.6929 - accuracy: 0.6042/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py:770: UserWarning: Possibly corrupt EXIF data.  Expecting to read 32 bytes but only got 0. Skipping tag 270
  " Skipping tag %s" % (size, len(data), tag)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py:770: UserWarning: Possibly corrupt EXIF data.  Expecting to read 5 bytes but only got 0. Skipping tag 271
  " Skipping tag %s" % (size, len(data), tag)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py:770: UserWarning: Possibly corrupt EXIF data.  Expecting to read 8 bytes but only got 0. Skipping tag 272
  " Skipping tag %s" % (size, len(data), tag)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py:770: UserWarning: Possibly corrupt EXIF data.  Expecting to read 8 bytes but only got 0. Skipping tag 282
  " Skipping tag %s" % (size, len(data), tag)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py:770: UserWarning: Possibly corrupt EXIF data.  Expecting to read 8 bytes but only got 0. Skipping tag 283
  " Skipping tag %s" % (size, len(data), tag)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py:770: UserWarning: Possibly corrupt EXIF data.  Expecting to read 20 bytes but only got 0. Skipping tag 306
  " Skipping tag %s" % (size, len(data), tag)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py:770: UserWarning: Possibly corrupt EXIF data.  Expecting to read 48 bytes but only got 0. Skipping tag 532
  " Skipping tag %s" % (size, len(data), tag)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py:788: UserWarning: Corrupt EXIF data.  Expecting to read 2 bytes but only got 0. 
  warnings.warn(str(msg))
500/500 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6609 - accuracy: 0.6318
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-bd0e48768399> in <module>()
----> 1 r = model.fit(x=train_batches,validation_data=valid_batches,epochs=5)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57     if name is not None:

UnknownError: Graph execution error:

2 root error(s) found.
  (0) UNKNOWN:  UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fb8672df290>
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 271, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 642, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1004, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 830, in wrapped_generator
    for data in generator_fn():

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 956, in generator_fn
    yield x[i]

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py", line 65, in __getitem__
    return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py", line 230, in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples
    interpolation=self.interpolation)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py", line 114, in load_img
    img = pil_image.open(io.BytesIO(f.read()))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2896, in open
    "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)

PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fb8672df290>


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
  (1) CANCELLED:  Function was cancelled before it was started
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_test_function_69081]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EXIF data of some images are corrupt, so PIL reading the images fails during training.

Methods may fix it:

1. PIL : Please remove the damaged images from the training set first, for example, PetImages/Cat/666.jpg, and PetImages/Dog/11702.jpg. Please also refer to https://www.kaggle.com/code/sushovansaha9/cat-dog-classification-transferlearning-ipynb.
2. PIL : remove the EXIF data but keep the images.

> ```
> import piexif  
> piexif.remove(filename)
> ```

3. tf.io : just read the image without remove any images or EXIF:

> ```
> file = tf.io.read_file(filename)
> image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file)
> ```